# How to set scrollbar value property in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, properties, scrollbar

I do have a scrollbar and an input field (tempBuiten). I like the scrollbar to follow the value in the input field. So if a user set a value in that  field, I would like the scrollbar to move to that position.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

    If Not Intersect(Range("tempBuiten"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       ' I use 10 as an test value for now
       ws1.ScrollBarBuiten.Value = 10
    End If

End Sub
```

I get: method or data member not found.

I am not sure if this is possible and how to do it if it is?

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `=`?

Comment: You mean like this: 

`ws1.ScrollBarBuiten.Value 10`?

Still: method or data member not found

Comment: My fault. Remove the `.value` too. By the way, I guess you're writing in German?

Comment: Same problem. (btw Dutch)

Comment: are you sure ScrollBarBuiten exist?

Comment: @Jelly OP is writing in Dutch so I am guessing yes but yea may not....

Comment: @ProX yea, as Jelly suggests, you might want to double check syntax. Perhaps `ws1.ScrollBar 10`? I am just guessing now XD

Comment: If I right-click on a scrollbar I can give it a name. I named it "ScrollBarBuiten". I thought that means it does exist. Can I control if it exists another way?

Comment: Oh. Is this a scrollbar for a table or something? Then I don't think you qualify it with the worksheet.

Comment: I added an image of the thing I like to do.

Comment: Ok yea, the scrollbar is a standalone object. Don't qualify it with the worksheet. Try `ScrollBarBuiten.Value = 10`

Comment: Found it :)

` ws1.Shapes("ScrollBarBuiten").ControlFormat.Value = 10`

Answer (score 3):

To set the scrollbars current value, I did find this sollution:

```
ws1.Shapes("ScrollBarBuiten").ControlFormat.Value = 10
```

Comment: Ah should have set it first XD Just fyi, try to be more detailed in your question next time. Your comments should have been included in OP.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the lingo yet ;) 
What do you mean with "set it first XD"?
And how could I have been more detailed in my question? I tried to add as much info as I did have myself (I am new to VBA).

And do you mean I should not react to the comments with a comment?

I hope to learn this from you; thanks in advance and sry for the inconvenience if I did mess up.

Comment: Unless you specify scrollbar, users will default to excel app scrollbar which in this case it was not. Could also include `ScrollBarBuiten` is what you named it. Try `set scrollBuiten=ws1.Shapes("ScrollBarBuiten")` then `scrollBuiten.ControlFormat.Value = 10`